# result confirm a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Hola estoy teniendo el siguiente problema.

En un archivo de PHP tengo...

```
echo($strconfirm ="<script>confirm('Registro repetido!!!');</script>");
if ($strconfirm == true){
echo "Selecciono si";
}else{
echo "Selecciono NO";
}
```

Pero no me guarda `true` o `false`.

Solo quiero guardar el valor de `confirm` en una variable para evaluarla con el `if`.

Saludos

Comment: Estás mezclando motor (backend) con interfaz (frontend). Un PHP no puede "esperar" a la respuesta del usuario de un javascript si no hay comunicación de vuelta al servidor tras aceptar. O bien hacerlo sólo en el lado del cliente. ¿Quieres un ejemplo de ambos?

Comment: No puedes mezclar ambas cosas como dice @OscarGarcia tendrías que hacer la petición desde javascript vía ajax para obtener el valor y procesarlo en el front.

Comment: Tampoco es necesario XHR, con un formulario normal también se podría :)

Answer (score 0):

Toda la interacción con el usuario que intentas desarrollar se desarrolla únicamente en el lado del cliente, en su navegador, usando un lenguaje de programación diferente a PHP, que se ejecuta una única vez en el servidor.

Debes entender que el servidor genera una página HTML usando el lenguaje de programación PHP y que ese HTML es interpretado (después de haber sido generado y enviado al cliente) en un navegador y no tendrá relación con el servidor hasta que el usuario vuelva a pulsar un enlace o enviar un formulario (o se use alguna función asíncrona XHR).

**Todo en el lado del cliente**

```js
resultado = confirm('Registro repetido!!!');
if (resultado == true) {
  document.write("Selecciono SI");
} else {
  document.write("Selecciono NO");
}
```

Verás que funciona todo en local, sin necesidad de un servidor PHP que reciba la respuesta.

**Envío de la respuesta mediante un formulario a un PHP**

```js
resultado = confirm('Registro repetido!!!');
document.formu.resultado.value = resultado;
document.formu.submit();
```

```html
<form action="receptor.php" method="post" name="formu">
<input type="hidden" name="resultado"/>
</form>
```

En este caso, cuando respondes trata de enviar el formulario a `receptor.php`, y como éste no existe en el servidor de stackoverflow te lanza un error, pero si lo ejecutas en tu servidor y tienes dicho script en PHP, recibirá el resultado en él.